# Saiku with Pentaho is dead?

Tags: pentaho, saiku

We used saiku3.17 with pentaho, but we can't claim  community license for saiku3.

Saiku4 is alive? I found just a docker install guide, and just without pentaho.

Saiku is dead?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: [tumbleweeds] I'm interested to know this too

Comment: We found it: not alive. We chose a cheap software seektable.